# nginx allow a single IP then deny all not working

Tags: nginx

I'm temporarily limiting my site to my single IP while debugging and tuning.  Unfortunately. nginx allow of my IP then deny all doesn't seem to be doing the job!

I know there are 'denied' IPs connected as the following returns a list of many:

```
netstat -anp | grep -E ":80|:443" | grep ESTABLISHED
```

My minimal nginx.conf:

```
server {
    server_name myserver.com;
    root /var/www/myserver;

    index index.php;

    include global/restrictions.conf;

    allow 107.77.323.112; # allowed IP address
    deny all;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
            include fastcgi.conf;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7.2-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
            fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
            fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
    }

    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /home/admin/myserver_com.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/admin/-myserver.com.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
}
```

Comment: I moved the allow & deny statements up to the http block and that doesn't help.

Comment: I guess there does have to be a connection made to nginx to return a 403.  It just looks to me that the connections I'm seeing are more persistent than returning a quick 403 result.

Answer (score 0):

nginx deny does not prevent a connection, a brief connection is made to return a 403 error.

netstat results might appear like there are many connections open over time, but a closer look will show that the port numbers are changing even if the number of connections is staying relatively constant. The same clients are just retrying to connect.

This little bash snippet was very useful in analyzing the connections.

```
sudo netstat -anp | grep -E ":80|:443" | grep ESTABLISHED | cut -c 43-64 | uniq | sort
```

I ran it multiple times waiting each time and outputting it to a different file. Then I compared files over time to find common lines:

```
grep -Fxf t1.txt t2.txt
```

I found there might be a few connections left from t1.txt to t2.txt, but a little later, t1.txt vs. t3.txt I found no remaining connections. In other words all the connections were new.